# Use Google Cloud Scheduler to get a Pandas Data Frame loaded into Google Big Query?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm following the documentation from the link below.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_gbq.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_gbq

Everything is setup perfectly fine in my data frame.  Now, I'm trying to export if to GBQ.  Here's a one-liner that should pretty much work...but it doesn't...

```
pandas_gbq.to_gbq(my_df, 'table_in_gbq', 'my_project_id', chunksize=None, reauth=False, if_exists='append', private_key=False, auth_local_webserver=True, table_schema=None, location=None, progress_bar=True, verbose=None)
```

I'm having a lot of trouble getting the cloud scheduler to run the job successfully.  The scheduler runs, and I see a message saying the 'Result' was a 'Success', but actually, and no data is loaded into Big Query.  When I run the job on the client side, everything is fine.  When I run it from the server, no data gets loaded.  I'm guessing, the credentials are throwing it off, but I can't tell for sure what's going on.  All I know for sure is that Google says the job runs successfully, but no data is loaded into my table.

My question is, how can I modify this to run using Google Cloud Scheduler, with minimal security, so I can rule out some kind of security issue?  Or, otherwise determine exactly what's going on here?

Comment: I got this to work: df.to_gbq(my_df, table_in_gbq, chunksize=None, verbose=None, reauth=False, if_exists='fail', private_key=None, auth_local_webserver=False, table_schema=None)